# jQuery does not work when fancybox is open and active

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, fancybox

I'm developing a plugin for WordPress, I used jQuery's `fancybox` to display my form, but I found a problem that I'm not able to solve, I'm trying to hide the second select of the form according to the value that the user selects in the first select:

My form code:

```html
<div style="display:none;" id="hidden-content">
   <h2>Lembrete de Recompra</h2>
   <p>Selecione o período em que deseje receber a notificação de lembrete para esse pedido </p>
   <form action="" method="get">
      <label for="periodo">Período:</label> 
      <select id="periodo" name="periodo" required >
         <option value=""> </option>
         <option value="dia">Diário</option>
         <option value="semana">Semanal</option>
         <option value="mes">Mensal</option>
      </select>
      <br/>
      <label for="dia-semana" id="day_week" style="margin-top:5px;">Dia da semana:</label> 
      <select id="dia_semana" name="dia_semana" required style="display:block;">
         <option value=""> </option>
         <option value="segunda">Segunda-feira</option>
         <option value="terca">Terça-Feira</option>
         <option value="quarta">Quarta-Feira</option>
         <option value="quinta">Quinta-Feira</option>
         <option value="quinta">Sexta-Feira</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" id="hidden_order_id" name="hidden_order_id" value="">
      <p></p>
      <input type="submit" value="Ativar Lembrete">
   </form>
</div>
```

This is where I add fancybox and put my form:
cdn facybox links:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.min.css

`a.woocommerce-button.button.form_btn_remember`  is the button the user clicks on and fancybox opens

```
jQuery('a.woocommerce-button.button.form_btn_remember').attr('data-fancybox','').attr('data-src','#hidden-content');
```

Form screenshot:

[image]

With fancybox enabled, the code below does not work
jQuery code:

```js
jQuery(document).on('change', '#periodo', function(){
  console.log('Teste');

  if (jQuery('#periodo').val() == 'dia') {
    jQuery('#dia_semana').hide();
    jQuery('#day_week').hide();
  } else {
    jQuery('#dia_semana').show();
    jQuery('#day_week').show();
  }
});
```

This code snippet doesn't work, when I modify the period select the Test is printed to the console but jQuery, when `fancybox` is active, doesn't work.

Print console:

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you are using jQuery instead of just the shorthand `$`? You could also select `#periodo` to add the change listener to instead of specifying it with the optional argument for `on`. Styling option elements from a select element will be difficult. You may have to remove and add the option from the html instead of just attempting to use `.hide()` which affects css

Comment: yes, there's a reason when I try to use the $ it says that it's not declared, I've tried to get only the #period is to use change(), but the problem is just that when the facybox is active the JS and jQuery don't work, they don't can't do this jQuery('#periodo').val(); or $('#period').val(); it is null it's as if the select with period id didn't exist
@AsyncAwaitFetch

Comment: This task doesn't require jQuery, would you be opposed to accomplishing this in vanilla js? Are you trying to resolve the issues with your jQuery import?

Comment: After realizing you are not trying to style the option elements, and rather hide the entire second element, I can not replicate the issue with the demo you have provided.

Comment: "jQuery does not work when fancybox is open and active" - this is wrong and misleading statement. You have error in your own code and, since you did not provide a working demo where your issue could be inspected, it is not possible to help you.

Comment: @Janis 
I'm going to add the code snippet where I add the facybox and call the form